# What should be done if a question has its duplicate deleted?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-reopen

So I was going through the Reopen review queue and came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945566/how-long-should-a-page-take-to-render-after-it-has-been-received) (10k+), which points to another question as a duplicate, however the question linked was deleted 3 years ago (on or before 2nd February 2015).

The fact that the duplicate link question has been removed indicates that I should have voted to reopen, however the question itself would more likely fall under primarily opinion-based:

> How long should a page take to render after it has been received? I'm talking about initialization javascript and css.
>
> I know this should be considered with what an acceptable overall load time should be. And, I would like to see numbers on that too. I've heard 1-2 seconds, but would like links and reasoning.
>
> What is considered acceptable load time? What is not, where is the breaking point. I know it will come up that it depends what is going on, some operations are expected to take longer. For arguments sake, lets say the amount of time it should take to render search results.

Is there a consensus on what the appropriate action is in situations like this?

Should it have been reopened to be reclosed under a more appropriate reason or just left closed?

What about other questions that should be closed under a different reason from their current closure reason?

Comment: Imo, Reopen and close it as opinion based, will make less noise than the incoming bug report for dead link in a ducplicate notice.

Comment: @DragandDrop That's what I was thinking, it would be useful in the Reopen queue to have a "Close under new reason" option

Comment: And as deleted content is not included in Data Explorer. I can't find if there is anyother question in this state.

Comment: @NickA in this case - it's an off-topic question, with little views in 7 odd years and without much content that doesn't describe itself as "this can't really be answered but..."... I've just removed the question - no one's going to miss out by its absence.

Comment: @JonClements I saw and updated the question to make more sense given the questions deleted status, anything to weigh in or possible duplicate links for this question on what to do when a question that is closed should be closed under a different reason (not just under this rare circumstance)

Comment: @DragandDrop there will be some prior to the changes that prohibited posts that are duplicate targets being deleted... in the grand scheme of things - they're really not something to worry about though.

Comment: @NickA if you have a gold badge and can find another duplicate and want to - then reopening/reclosing as a duplicate (or editing the duplicates list) for the post is fine. While the target duplicate isn't available to users not 10k+ - others can still see it. The only potential issue is that non-logged in users visiting the page might be redirected to the duplicate (I'm not sure if the redirect checks the target is visible before doing so).

Comment: If a question should remain closed but *technically* closed for another reason - it's generally not worth the time getting the necessary re-open votes and then the necessary close votes. For questions that aren't viewed much and are years old - think of the fact it's closed for whatever reason as doing what a closure does - stop new answers. The fact the close *reason* might not be completely accurate isn't that big a thing.

Comment: for some with delvotes to spare / editing: the complete SEDE query here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/209965/duplicates-of-deleted-questions

Comment: In a sane system, it shouldn't be possible in the first place to delete a question of which another one is marked a duplicate.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre 1,685 rows? I may have to take back my previous comment of this being a *rare* circumstance

Comment: Yeah, I wonder how this could happen. You cannot delete a question with a bounty, you cannot delete a locked question, so why can you delete a question with duplicate? Well, let's suppose that the "original" question was deleted for a good reason, then the duplicates should also be deleted.

Comment: It seems that it was possible to close as duplicate with a target where no answer was posted or upvoted or accepted, which isn't the case anymore. I picked one at random, and the original question was roombaed because no answer and negative score!

Comment: @Jean-François unless you're a mod I don't recall (could well be wrong - I only joined in 2012) it ever being possible (child metas are exempt) of being able to close as a duplicate something that has no answers, an upvoted, accepted or otherwise. Before my time on SO though, closing as duplicate wasn't a *real thing* - all that happened is that the Community bot *edited* the post to include a banner and users could edit the post to edit that banner etc...

Comment: @JonClements No I never was a mod, I only joined in 2016 for my 18th birthday :) that's okay, thanks, I already asked a real meta question in the meanwhile.

Comment: The only thing of concern here should be: is the question fine and on-topic. If not, nobody cares about it. Delete it, close it, doesn't matter how. Don't spend time pondering what to do with crap, just remove it from the site. People who start meta tasks like "oh, this was the wrong close reason, lets re-open this, then close it as something else" are just wasting everyone's time. This question seems both too broad and opinion-based it, so just delete it and be done with it.

Comment: @Lundin Sure in this case, but it won't always be the case that a question that is a duplicate is also off topic

Comment: @NickA If it is a duplicate, then the only reason you would want to re-open it is if it's actually of better quality than the linked duplicate (question + answers). Then it should be opened and the linked post should be closed instead. Otherwise, nobody could care what happens to it. Particularly if it is from 2010.

Comment: @Lundin Hm. Are you saying that if the original gets deleted, because quality, it follows that the duplicate cannot be very good either, otherwise it couldn't have been closed as a dup of the bad one to begin with? You have a point there, but I still think this should be looked at on a case-by-case basis. Don't draw blanket conclusions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got hold of a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/209965/duplicates-of-deleted-questions) (I didn't write it, since I don't have a clue how to do it, but got it from a [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) user) to display those cases precisely

There seem to be several sub-cases here:

#### 1. Duplicate of Roombaed questions

The original question has been deleted because it was closed, and didn't have any answer or upvoted answer (Roombaed). In that case, it should probably be reopened if it has some upvotes, or deleted if as unsalvageable as the original question (note that I find that strange that recent questions could be closed with an original question which is Roombable)

#### 2. Duplicates of questions with answers, but which were bad, so downvoted & put on hold/unclear, then deleted by 10k+ users

In that case, the timeline is probably:

- question asked
- question closed as duplicate of a non-deleted question (closed or not)
- original question gets downvoted/deleted

The original was deleted because it was off-topic, so the duplicate is also off-topic, and should be deleted as well (unless it was a mistake and the question is salvageable)

#### What now?

So now you have the up-to-date list, so 10k+ users & gold badge owners (& others), get to work to salvage or bury those dead-end questions if you have some time & delete/reopen votes to spare.

Comment: This seems tangential to the question asked here. It seems it should be its own independent question and get addressed by the community on its own grounds.

Comment: Well, question asks "what should be done", I'm answering what I think should be done, with, added, the script to find all the cases. Of course, I'm not a meta established user, I only answer when I think I can help. Can you elaborate on "should be its own independent question" ?

Comment: It seems it's almost its own campaign on dealing with things that should be discussed by the community as a whole - rather than being an answer about a specific case.

Comment: ok, so you're advising me to ask a new question with more or less the contents of this answer, but more open, to look more like taking advice? I could do that.

Comment: Yes, if you'd like. Make it a very clear question for discussion and links etc... and why it's a "good thing" - put your point across etc... you can't do that in an answer as the discussion should be on the question.

Comment: Just FYI: Voting to delete/undelete questions which have been closed > 2 days is a [10k+ privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) The [20k+ privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) is answers with score < 0 and questions < 2 days closed, but with score < -2.

Comment: @Makyen of course I know that. I'm practically living at SOCVR :)

Comment: It is possible to close a question as a duplicate of a question by the same user even if the target doesn't have any answers. This is likely the case for the roombaed ones.

Comment: @TinyGiant now I know :p https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363895/how-is-it-possible-to-close-as-duplicate-with-a-non-answered-original-question

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you for your SEDE, but would it be possible to filter out duplicates of migrated questions like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624540/random-avatar-generator

Comment: @Cœur I didn't write the script. But I'll make my enquiries.

Comment: @Coeur check the author of the query, seems to be animuson (moderator I think)