# How is it possible to close as duplicate with a non-answered original question?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

I was just answering this meta question: [What should be done if a question has its duplicate deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363892/what-should-be-done-if-a-question-has-its-duplicate-deleted).

In my answer I provided the link to a [SEDE script](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/209965/duplicates-of-deleted-questions) which lists the questions closed as duplicate, with original questions which got deleted.

I wanted to perform a sampling of those questions, and I found out that some of them (I only checked a few, but there are probably a lot) link to recent deleted questions.

So how is it possible in 2017 to close as duplicate if the original question has no accepted or upvoted answer? I already tried that and was denied by the close widget.

- [Olympiad in C++ , no idea how to solve completely: I'm trying to make a program which would get the total pineapple count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777185/olympiad-in-c-no-idea-how-to-solve-completely-im-trying-to-make-a-program) is recent (2017, so after the new duplicate policy) and points to a deleted downvoted on-hold question but deleted by *community* (not roombaed, though), and not 20k+ users
- [scrape google search images in another way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589972/scrape-google-search-images-in-another-way): same case
- [how to get data from sqlite database into listview and the second activity use Viewpager in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48732299/how-to-get-data-from-sqlite-database-into-listview-and-the-second-activity-use-v): duplicate of roombaed

I know it was possible some time ago but the policy of closing as duplicates changed ([We should be able to close questions as duplicates of any question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165928/we-should-be-able-to-close-questions-as-duplicates-of-any-question)).

Someone can explain what's going on?

Comment: In addition to Servy's answer, [the answer was accepted when it as alive](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46776003/timeline).  When the Q gets deleted it removes the accepted from the answer.

Comment: yeah, I know that, sometimes the timeline is tricky. Your link shows 2 events: answer, then "accept" by community;.. Anyway, glad to know that the system still works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- If the author of both questions is the same you can close as a duplicate. (This appears to be the case for your second and third examples.)
- Moderators can do this.
- The answer could have been deleted after it was marked as a duplicate.
- The answer could have been downvoted/unupvoted/unaccepted after it was marked as a duplicate. (This is the case for your first example.  The answer was accepted, and unaccepted automatically when the post was deleted.  (Deleted posts can't be accepted.))